# Wrong type error on an interface intended to test a method using Docker's client API

Tags: testing, go, docker

I'm refactoring a program I wrote so I can properly write tests for it. One of the first methods I'd like to test is a method that uses [Docker's client API](https://github.com/docker/docker/tree/master/client) to see if a certain image exists on a Docker host.

To be able to test this method, I created an interface that matches `client.ImageList`'s [signature](https://godoc.org/github.com/docker/docker/client#Client.ImageList):

```
type ImageLister interface {
    ImageList(ctx context.Context, options types.ImageListOptions) ([]types.ImageSummary, error)
}
```

I also changed the method to test to take an `ImageLister` as argument, so I can pass in an `ImageLister` implementation specific to my tests.

However, in my actual code, where I pass in the "real" Docker client to the method to test, the following compilation error occurs:

> ImageExists:
>           *client.Client does not implement ImageLister (wrong type for ImageList method)
>               have ImageList("github.com/docker/docker/vendor/golang.org/x/net/context".Context, types.ImageListOptions) ([]types.ImageSummary, error)
>               want ImageList("context".Context, types.ImageListOptions) ([]types.ImageSummary, error)

How can I resolve this? Or is my approach bad anyway, and should I go a different route?

edit:
The following program reproduces the issue I'm encountering.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types"
    "github.com/docker/docker/client"
)

type ImageLister interface {
    ImageList(ctx context.Context, options types.ImageListOptions) ([]types.ImageSummary, error)
}

func main() {
    client, err := client.NewEnvClient()
    defer client.Close()

    ImageExists(context.TODO(), client, "foo")
}

func ImageExists(ctx context.Context, lister ImageLister, image string) (bool, error) {
    return true, nil
}
```

Comment: Docker vendors dependencies. If you want to use docker as a library you need to properly vendor it yourself.

Comment: Installing `govendor`, running `govendor add +external` and replacing my `context` imports with `golang.org/x/net/context` did seem to resolve this. If you could post that as an answer, I'll accept it. In the mean while, it seems I have some reading to do about vendoring in go! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `github.com/docker/docker/` package has "vendored" its dependencies in the `github.com/docker/docker/vendor` directory. While a package in a `vendor/` directory is imported by it's normal import path, the types are still matched by their full path to avoid incompatibilities if a package is inadvertently imported multiple times. Because of this, when sharing types between packages, both packages need to import the dependency from the same path.

The way to handle this is to properly vendor the docker package, which means moving the packages used by docker up to the top-level vendor directory. Various tools like `govendor` or `glide` can do this for you, and there is work on an "official" tool for dependency management right now too.

Answer (score 1):

#### Argument types

The method declared in the interface wants local type `context.Context` but the implemented method expects `Context` from docker. This two entities are absolutely different types so `ImageLister` interface is not implemented with `*client.Client`.

#### Named imports

I believe the problem is here:

> want ImageList("context".Context...

It means your local package named "context". Since docker has a package "context" (github.com/docker/docker/vendor/golang.org/x/net/context) this fact creates a naming ambiguity and could cause some issues.

[Import declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Import_declarations):

> Assume we have compiled a package containing the package clause package math, which exports function Sin, and installed the compiled package in the file identified by "lib/math". This table illustrates how Sin is accessed in files that import the package after the various types of import declaration.

```
// Import declaration          Local name of Sin

import   "lib/math"        // math.Sin
import m "lib/math"        // m.Sin
import . "lib/math"        // Sin
```

Use named imports to resolve this ambiguity:

```
import (
    ctx "github.com/docker/docker/vendor/golang.org/x/net/context"
)
```

Comment: I agree the error message is clear, and I think the issue arises from the fact `context` was vendored in the Docker client API (am I right about that?), which I don't have any control over. So that doesn't help me much in resolving the issue itself.

Comment: I would presume that the local package implements `Context` and shadowed `Context` from docker.

Comment: That sounds logical. I tried using the Docker vendored `context` package, but this is not allowed by the compiler: `imports github.com/docker/docker/vendor/golang.org/x/net/context: use of vendored package not allowed`

Comment: Try to rename your local package.

Comment: I now import local context as `localContext "context"`, and changed the signature of my interface to have `ctx localContext.Context` as one of the arguments, this still results in the same error. I cannot import the Docker's vendored `context`, because the compiler doesn't allow that (see previous comment).

Comment: That's really odd, because the project refers to exactly these packages to use as the client API. So if I understand correctly, there's not much I can do myself to resolve this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135380/discussion-between-i159-and-bcd).